# Error while defining enum values in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, enums

```
class Klass < ApplicationRecord

  enum dimension: { length: 'length', breadth: 'breadth' }
end
```

I'm getting the following error :-

> ArgumentError: You tried to define an enum named "name" on the model
>   "Klass", but this will generate a class method "length", which is
>   already defined by ActiveRecord::Relation.

I just want to know what are my options to get dimension enum working with `length` as one of its value. Is it possible to create the enum without defining `length` method on the model ?

Comment: Why would you want to do this in the first place? If you models just have two dimensions tops why do you want to add another layer of joins and complexity? This stinks of the EAV anti-pattern.

Comment: @max I have simplified my code and renamed the values to some generic ones. The original one has many values, with one value being length.

Comment: Why not just add a two columns to the table that actually has the attribute so that you don't have to create ridiculous `Thing.joins(:attributes).where(dimension: 'length', value: 15)` queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`length` is a reserved method name. So, you can't use this reserved method name.

you can try like using the prefix :

```
class Klass < ApplicationRecord
  enum dimension: { length: 'length', breadth: 'breadth' }, _prefix: :dimension
end
```

> **Note**:
>    Class method "length", which is already defined by ActiveRecord::Relation.

Comment: `length` is not a keyword. Its a method name. Keywords are words with special significance in the language like `if`, `else`, `class`, `module`.

Comment: I changed as per suggestion(@max)